# windowsのリモートデスクトップを用いてプロキシ経由でCentOSに接続したい

Tags: linux, centos, windows-10

Windows 10 のPCからRDP対応のプロキシーサーバ（踏み台サーバ）を経由してCentOS7にリモートデスクトップ接続したいと思っています。

既にCentOS7側には下記のコマンドを投入しており、firewallも設定をしていない状況です。

```
sudo -E yum install epel-release -y
sudo -E yum install xrdp tigervnc-server -y
sudo systemctl start xrdp
sudo systemctl enable xrdp
```

ここからWindowsの `mstsc` を起動してリモートデスクトップを行いたいのですが、単純にCentOS7のIPアドレスを入れるだけだと、プロキシーを超えられないので、その設定をどうにか入れたいと思っています。

Comment: RDP対応プロクシでしょうか？ それとも無関係なプロトコルのプロクシでしょうか？

Comment: この記事あたりが参考になるかも。[RDP Over SSH or RDP with HTTP-Proxy (Or Any Protocol over SSH)](http://my-techno-arena.blogspot.com/2016/02/rdp-over-ssh-or-rdp-with-http-proxy.html), [SSH ポートフォワディングで社内 PROXY 環境から AWS にリモートデスクトップ接続する](https://qiita.com/saitotak/items/7b6ea6b5f61668508aa0)